# EJB3 annotations get ignored when ejb-jar.xml is present

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, java-ee-6, ejb-3.1, ejb-2.x

I have an application that currently consists of EJB 2.1 Session Beans. I want to transport them to EJB 3.1 annotations where possible.

Unfortunately that is not possible for all so I need to maintain the `ejb-jar.xml` file for the ones where I can't use the annotations.

I have added the `beans.xml` file but as long as I have the `ejb-jar.xml` file present, the annotations are ignored. As soon as I remove it, the annotations work.

How can I configure my application to use the annotations where present and use the `ejb-jar.xml` file only for stuff thats configured inside it. As far as I understood the documentation, this should be the normal case anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you shift your application from EJB-2.1 to EJB-3.1 you have to check that you set the version of the `ejb-jar.xml` to 3.1 as well.

Use this header from the [the xsd](http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_1.xsd):

```xml
<ejb-jar xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_1.xsd"
      version="3.1">
```

Then your annotations are considered then as well.

The `beans.xml` is not needed for this at all. It is required for enabling CDI (which you don't need if you only refer to your beans from other beans), have a look at [this post](http://www.seamframework.org/Documentation/WhatIsBeansxmlAndWhyDoINeedIt.html) about what it is and when you need it.

You might need other settings to your `ejb-jar.xml` as well but that is a topic for another question.